# How to customize the JSON output depending on the value of a Option type in the case class?

Tags: scala, playframework

Say I have a case class like:

```
case class KVP(customKey: Option[String], value: String)
```

I can create a JSON writes method like:

```
implicit val kvpWrites: Writes[KVP] = (
    ( __ \ "customKey").write[Option[String]] and
    ( __ \ "value").write[String]

)(unlift(KVP.unapply))
```

So the JSON will look something like for `KVP("location", "NY")`

```
{
   "customKey": "location",
   "value": "NY"
}
```

But what I want is this, if `customKey` has a value I want:

```
{
    "location": "NY"
}
```

if `customKey` is a None, I want:

```
{
    "value": "NY"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `Writes` like this:

```scala
implicit val kvpWrites: OWrites[KVP] = new OWrites[KVP] {
  def writes(kvp: KVP): JsObject = {
    // Build a JsValue by yourself
    Json.obj(Seq(kvp.customKey.getOrElse("value") -> kvp.value))
  }
}
```

Or simplified:

```scala
implicit val kvpWrites: OWrites[KVP] = OWrites[KVP] { (kvp: KVP) =>
  Json.obj(Seq(kvp.customKey.getOrElse("value") -> kvp.value))
}
```

Comment: Everywhere possible, rather use `OWrites` instead of `Writes`, and factory `OWrites[T]{ t => ...}` is more convenient/less verbose than subclassing, using `Json.obj` instead of `JsObject` constructor.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @cchantep